# $cookies.get shows undefined

Tags: angularjs, cookies

i'm trying to save data in cookies, but the cookies module doesnt seems to work, the angular i'm working on is 1.7.8

i've added the ngcookies modules
and tried different versions of angular

```
var gestione = angular.module('gestione',['ngCookies']);
gestione.controller('login',['$scope','$cookies',function($scope,$cookies){
var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
// Setting a cookie
$cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
console.log($cookies.get('myFavorite'));
}]);
```

ithe console displays undefined.

Comment: have you console log 'oatmeal'  before putting in cookies?

Comment: oatmeal is a string, not a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can read Documentation of cookies here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies
I think it was helpfull for you!

Comment: thank you but i already saw and followed the example in this documantation. still didn't work, the code above is from their example